# Method "glActiveTexture" not available

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I'm starting to get into libGDX game engine. I have copied [this](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/OrthographicCamera) example and tried to run.
It runs ok as android application, but when i want it to run as java application it throws the following error.

> Exception in thread "Thread-2" javax.media.opengl.GLException:
>   javax.media.opengl.GLException: Method "glActiveTexture" not available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should change this line: `GL10 gl = Gdx.graphics.getGL10();` to `GL20 gl = Gdx.graphics.getGL20();`. Because according to the official OpenGL documentation:

> glActiveTexture is only supported if the GL version is 1.3 or greater, or if ARB_multitexture is included in the string returned by glGetString when called with the argument GL_EXTENSIONS.

The difference may lie in the fact that Windows by default gives a OpenGL 1.1 context and only offers all the additional functionality via extensions (i.e. `glActiveTextureARB()` which the Java OpenGL might not use)

Answer (score 0):

I`ve got this error. 
GLView (or other program to view GL version) show me, that my current OpenGL is 1.1 and this method is only on 1.3 and higher. 
My solution wat to update drivers with Windows Update (My driver - ATI technologies Inc. driver update for ATI radeon). After update to version 3.0 all is fine.